# configuring rails3 route with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

**What I have**

```
match "/home/markread/:id" => "books#markread"
```

goes to

```
def markread
  #mark params[:id] as read
end
```

**What I want**

What If I want to pass another parameter so that urls looks like
`/home/markread/1/didread=read` or `/home/markread/1/didread=unread`

so my method will change to

```
def marked
  #mark params[:id] as params[:didread]
end
```

**Question**

what should my `routes.rb` look like for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just changing to

```
match "home/markread/:id/used=:used" => "books#markread"
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the route a name using the 'as' option and pass the optional parameters as many you want.

For example:

```
match "/home/markread/:id" => "books#markread", :as => 'markread'
```

This will give you helpers like, `markread_path` and `markread_url`. You can pass the `parameters like markread_path(:id => 1, :other => 'value' ...)`

You need to do the checks in the controller for that action whether a particular parameter is passed or not. [Rails Doc.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: from the example you provided...will I still be able to pass in more than one parameter?

Comment: Yes. You can pass in as many parameters as you want. Decide what you want to do with them in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4 you will have:

```
    resources :home, only: :none do
      get 'markread/:another', action: :markread, on: :member
    end
```

`GET /home/:id/markread/:another(.:format)      /home#markread`